# qt connect to oracle database on windows

Tags: c++, oracle, qt, oracle-call-interface

On Windows 7 I installed qt creator and now I am trying to connect to the oracle database. I installed oracle client and plsql/developer and everything works fine. In qt creator I have error:

> QsqlDatabase: QOCI driver not loaded

This [qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qoci) does not work for me. Is it clear tutorial how to do it on different platforms and situations?

Comment: Is QOCI plugin built?

Comment: how about building the QOCI driver yourself ? plus what version of Qt are you using ?

Comment: qt version is 5.1.1. and how to build QOCI driver by myself? is there any clear tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I found solution.

Documentation says

> set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;c:\oracle\oci\include
>
> set LIB=%LIB%;c:\oracle\oci\lib\msvc
>
> cd %QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\oci
>
> qmake oci.pro
>
> nmake
>
> If you are not using a Microsoft compiler, replace nmake with make in
>   the line above.

but **make** or **nmake** didn't work for me. Because I have not installed **Microsoft Visual c++** on my machine.

***I made instruction how to do this:***

1. At first don't forget to install qt sources. During the installation check **Sources** checkbox.
2. then download and install oracle client [win32_11gR2_client.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html). choose **Runtime** option during installation.(even if you are using 64 bit os download 32 bit version on oracle client). It creates c:\app\user\product\client_1... directory
3. then open qt **minGW command line**(start ->all peograms -> qt[version] -> [version] -> MinGW [version] -> Qt [version] for Desktop MinGW [version]) and move to the oci source folder:

> **cd C:\Qt\Qt[version]\[version]\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\oci**

4. then as documentation says include OCI(Oracle call interface) path and library:

> **set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;c:\app\user\product[version]\client_1\oci\include**
>
> **set LIB=%LIB%;c:\app\user\product[version]\client_1\oci\lib\msvc**

5.compile oci driver by executing these two lines:

> **qmake oci.pro**
>
> **mingw32-make**

it will creates two .dll files for you **qsqloci.dll**(release version) and **qsqlocid.dll**(debug version)

6. last step is to copy these two files into qtcreator installation folder.
   go to the:

> **C:\Qt\Qt[version]\[version]\Src\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers**

and copy these files into:

> **C:\Qt\Qt[version]\[version]\mingw[version]\plugins\sqldrivers**

and you are ready to go. to check connection try this code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI");
    db.setHostName("MY_IP_OR_HOST_NAME");
    db.setDatabaseName("XE");
    db.setUserName("test");
    db.setPassword("test_password");

    if (!db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "Wow opened";
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `QODBC` instea of `QOCI`.

Answer (score 0):

`gogagubi`'s answer is good, but step 4 does not work for me because set `INCLUDE` and `LIB` does not work for `mingw32-make`.

It need to set `INCPATH` and `LIBS` in `oci.pro` or use:

```
qmake "INCPAH +=c:\app\user\product[version]\client_1\oci\include 
       LIBS +=-Lc:\app\user\product[version]\client_1\oci\lib\msvc" oci.pro
```

Add the following lines to the `oci.pro`:

```
INCPATH +=c:\app\user\product[version]\client_1\oci\include
LIBS+=-Lc:\app\user\product[version]\client_1\oci\lib\msvc
```

Answer (score 0):

ciao tutto;
you can connect to oracle db with QODBC driver if it exist;(default in Qt windows is exist) Like below:

```
QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
   db.setConnectOptions();
   db.setDatabaseName("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=127.0.0.1:1521;Uid=ep;Pwd=605605");
   if(!db.open())
       exit(0);

   QSqlQuery query(db);
   query.exec("select * from t");
   while(query.next())
       QMessageBox::information(0,"",query.value(1).toString());
```

this is connected and allow to execurte query;
buona fortuna;